# How can we call an api in every 2 minutes in android N or higher versions even when the app is closed or killed

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I want a best consistent solution to call an api to update current location in every 2 minutes on Nougat and higher version. The process should not be terminated even when the app is killed or closed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use the background services

Comment: Can you provide an example? I believe some limitations are there for background services in N and O versions. I want to run a service in every 2 minutes in N and O versions

Comment: Create a stickyServices

Answer (score 2):

**Create a services:**

```html
public class MyServices extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startService(new Intent(this,MyServices.class));
        Timer t = new Timer();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();


        // Timer task makes your service will repeat after every 20 Sec.
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      //Do network call here
                    }

                });
            }
        };
        //Starts after 20 sec and will repeat on every 20 sec of time interval.
        t.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 3000,3000);  // 20 sec timer
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Register the service in menifest

```
 <service android:name=".MyServices" />
```

Start the service in your activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyServices.class);
 startService(intent);
```

if version > N use this

```
startForegroundService(intent);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this will work on Nougat? For me background service is working till Marshmellow but not in >=N

Comment: Try It if its work accept the answer will help other

Comment: Please use this startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ServedService.class)); greater then N

Answer (score 1):

Create a service and update from there.

Service will not stop after closing the application but it will get stopped if the application is force stopped.

And also if your app goes to doze mode your app cannot use Internet or GPS service from the background.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) to schedule any kind of work you want your app to do.

Comment: `WorkManager` cannot work every 2 minutes as of OP's requirement. Minimum `PeriodicWorkRequest` time is 15 minutes in workmanager.